# Mutation in axillary buds of trees overcoming self-incompatability?

Tags: genetics, botany, reproduction, mutations

I seem to recall from either reading or lecture that there have been instances of trees that are self-incompatible accumulating enough mutations in an axillary bud that the resulting branch was able to pollinate flowers on other parts of the tree. Unfortunately, I do not have a source for this information.

Are there recorded instances of this happening, or is this a figment of my fevered brain?

Comment: You may be remembering the line of work since reviewed here: https://www.nature.com/articles/hdy2013114 (Scofield DG. 2013. A definitive demonstration of fitness effects due to somatic mutation in a plant. Heredity 112:361–362.) Maybe you can clarify the question further, as well, if you are still interested one decade after the op?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, samples from different parts of cottonwood trees have been sequenced ([Nature News](http://www.nature.com/news/tree-s-leaves-genetically-different-from-its-roots-1.11156)). The conclusion:

> “The variation within a tree is as great as the variation across unrelated trees,” says Ken Paige, an evolutionary biologist at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, who led the team that made the discovery.

This doesn't say anything about overcoming self-incompatibility, and it probably depends on the mechanism of self-incompatibility if it can be overcome by accumulating mutations.

Comment: Going through my old Botany textbooks. It would appear that for at least one mechanism for self-incompatability, it would require between one and three *de novo* mutations. Perhaps for some mechanisms it would be more likely, and perhaps someone has come across this in the wild, but for now this works for me. :)